# list of model binding angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to bind data dynamically in angularJS model
But all numeric data are`0` or `null`
I use the code like this in another place and worked well but not working now

> The problem is my result is nothing

Result

```
{"id":"73","result":[{"helpState":"","hostRealls":0,"guestsRealls":0,"dateStart":null},{"helpState":"","hostRealls":0,"guestsRealls":0,"dateStart":null},{"helpState":"","hostRealls":0,"guestsRealls":0,"dateStart":null}]
```

My controller make html:

```
public virtual JsonResult getResult(int id)
    {
        string currentLanguage = LanguageHelpers.GetCurrentLanguageCode;

        var help = db.Helps.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(g => g.id == id && g.id_helpState == 6);

        string helpRow = help?.HelpRow?.HelpRowTitles?.FirstOrDefault(g => g.languageCode == currentLanguage)?.rowContent;

        var data = helpRow?.Split(';');

        ResultHelpViewModel model = new ResultHelpViewModel();
        model.result = new List<onlineResult>();
        var dataResult = help?.onlineResult?.Split(';');

        string html = "<table class=\"table table-striped\">";

        for (int i = 0; i <= help.rowCount; i++)
        {
            onlineResult onlineResult = new onlineResult();
            for (int k = 0; k < (dataResult?.Length ?? 0); k++)
            {
                var dataRowResult = dataResult[k]?.Split('=');
                var dataRowcontentResult = dataRowResult[1]?.Split(',');

                if (dataRowResult[0] == "h")
                    onlineResult.hostRealls = Convert.ToInt32(dataRowcontentResult[i] ?? "0");
                else if (dataRowResult[0] == "g")
                    onlineResult.guestsRealls = Convert.ToInt32(dataRowcontentResult[i] ?? "0");
                else if (dataRowResult[0] == "s")
                    onlineResult.helpState = dataRowcontentResult[i];
                //if (dataRowResult[0] == "s")
                //    onlineResult.dateStart =Convert.ToDateTime(dataRowcontentResult[i]??(DateTime.Now.ToString()));

            }
            model.result.Add(onlineResult);

            html += "<tr>";

            for (int j = 1; j < data.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                var dataRow = data[j].Split('=');
                var dataRowcontent = dataRow[1].Split(',');

                if (i < dataRowcontent.Length && dataRow[0] != "lb" && dataRow[0] != "ch" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataRowcontent[i]))
                    html += "<td>" + dataRowcontent[i] + "</td>";

                if (i != 0)
                {
                    if (j == 2)
                    {
                        html += "<td><input data-ng-model=\"help.result[" + i + "].dateStart\" type=\"text\" class =\"form-control text-center\" value=\"" + model?.result[i]?.dateStart + "\"/></td>";

                        html += "<td><select data-ng-model=\"help.result[" + i + "].helpState\"  class=\"form-control\">";
                        foreach (HelpStateResult result in Enum.GetValues(typeof(HelpStateResult)))
                        {
                            string selected = model?.result[i]?.helpState == ((int)result) + "" ? "selected = \"selected\"" : "";
                            html += "<option label=\"" + Shared_Function.GetEnumDescription(result) + "\" value=\"" + (int)result + "\" " + selected + "></option>";
                        }
                        html += "</select></td>";

                        html += "<td><input data-ng-model=\"help.result[" + i + "].hostRealls\" class =\"form-control text-center\" value=\"" + model?.result[i]?.hostRealls + "\" type=\"number\"/></td>";
                    }
                    if (j == data.Length - 3)
                        html += "<td><input data-ng-init=\"help.result[" + i + "].guestsRealls='" + model?.result[i]?.guestsRealls + "'\" data-ng-model=\"help.result[" + i + "].guestsRealls\"  class =\"form-control text-center\" value=\"" + model?.result[i]?.guestsRealls + "\" type=\"number\"/></td>";
                }
                else if (i == 0 && j == 2)
                    html += "<td>" + Resources.date + "</td>";
                else if (i == 0 && j == 3)
                    html += "<td>" + Resources.help_helpState + "</td>";
                else if (i == 0 && j == 4)
                    html += "<td>" + Resources.help_hostRealls + "</td>";                  
                else if (i == 0 && j == data.Length - 3)
                    html += "<td>" + Resources.help_guestsRealls + "</td>";
            }

            html += "</tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";

        model.html = html;

        return new JsonResult { Data = model, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Model

```
public class ResultHelpViewModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public List<onlineResult> result { get; set; }

    public string html { get; set; }
}

    public class onlineResult
{
    public string helpState { get; set; }

    public int hostRealls { get; set; }

    public int guestsRealls { get; set; }

    public DateTime? dateStart { get; set; }
}
```

AngularJS Controller

```
  $scope.result = function () {          
      $scope.help.id = $stateParams.id;
      $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/Help/Result',
          data: $scope.help,
          headers: {
              'RequestVerificationToken': $scope.antiForgeryToken
          }
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.message = '';
          $scope.errors = [];
          if (data.success === false) {
              $scope.errors = data.errors;
              var str = '';
              for (var error in data.errors) {
                  str += data.errors[error] + '\n';
              }
              $scope.message = str;
          }
          else {
              $state.go('app.listhelps');
          }
      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.errors = [];
          $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error new';
      });
  };
```

html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit='result()' data-ng-init="helpresult()" data-ng-controller="HelpCtrl">
    <input id="antiForgeryToken" data-ng-model="antiForgeryToken" type="hidden" data-ng-init="antiForgeryToken='@ViewBag.GetAntiForgeryToken()'" />
    <p compile data-ng-bind-html="to_trusted(help.html)"></p>
    <hr class="line-dashed line-full" />
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
        <a ui-sref="app.listhelps" class="btn btn-default">@Languages.Properties.Resources.btn_cancel</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">@Languages.Properties.Resources.btn_submit</button>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: don't understand why you need MVC to generate html when you are using angular and json data. Seems like you should consider decoupling the front end from the back end and only use back end to provide data and let angular do what it does well at rendering that data in templates

Comment: @charlietfl I load data from EF and need mvc or webApi to provide data. Thank you. But this is not my problem at this time

Comment: Your getResult action method is confusing to me. Why are you building the html markup in that method ?  you should use angular ng-repeat in your view code.

Comment: @Sinoheh I'd advise you to really move all that HTML from the controller into a View and just pass the model to the view, you can then return the rendered view to the JSON result

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes you are right :D. In another place user need to make field dynamically i used this method. But I don't know why I use this bad idea here!. Thank you. I will use `ng-repeat` in this place. Thank you

Comment: @Shyju yes bad code. I will fix this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case better use `ng-repeat` instead of sending html dynamically to controller.